# binomial confidence interval from multiple observations

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution

As far as I understand, a confidence interval for a population proportion (e.g. p = probability of a coin coming up heads) is constructed based on one observation of X=k, X~ binomial (n,p) (let's say k heads observed in n flips).

I am now thinking that if you have more data, e.g. k1, k2, k3 from the same distribution X ~ binomial (n,p), you have more information so you should be able to construct a narrower interval. Is that true, and if so, what is the method for doing that?

Comment: What do you mean by ", a confidence interval for the binomial p"

Comment: Can you clarify: Are you thinking of a case where e.g. you have a bag of *n* balls that are each either red, green, or blue, so that p1= blue/n, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

If $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are independent and identically distributed as
$\mathsf{Binom}(n, p),$ then 
$$S   = X_1 + X_2 + X_3 \sim \mathsf{Binom}(m=3n, p).$$

So you can   use $\hat p = S/m$ as the unbiased point estimate of $p.$
Then you can use your formula for a binomial confidence interval (CI)
to get an interval estimate. Use $S$ and $m$ instead
of $X$ and $n.$ A CI based on $3n$ observations will tend to be shorter than a CI based on $n$ observations (but not 1/3 the length).

I will not show the CI because several styles
of binomial CIs are in common use and you do not indicate which
one you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you make $n$ independent trials, but split these up into $n=n_1+n_2+n_3$ and compute $k_1$, $k_2$, $k_3$. As *BruceET* already mentioned this is not a good idea, because you use your data in an inefficient way and obtain too large confidence intervals.

I can only guess what your reasoning might be behind splitting up the trials; maybe it is based on biology textbooks which, [according to this ComputationlSciene question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/23570/30365) recommend this approach for error estimation. The idea behind this suggestion is to use the different results for cross-validation, but there are always better methods (see the discussion of the above question). In this particular case, this is pointless, because many good confidence intervals are known for a binomial $p$, see e.g.

> L. D. Brown, T. T. Cai, and A. DasGupta, “Interval estimation for a binomial proportion,”Statistical science, vol. 16, no. 2, pp. 101–117, 2001

Brown et al. recommend the Wilson interval, but if $p$ is close to one or zero, the [Bayesian HPD interval has even better coverage probability](https://lionel.kr.hsnr.de/~dalitz/data/publications/fb03-tb-2017-01-en.pdf). It can only be computed numerically, though. So if you need a closed formualy, go for the Wilson interval.